# Structure pointer C language

Tags: c, string, buffer-overflow

I"m trying to load values into my structure but it's attaching the first element of every new structure to the last of the previous.

Initially I had the 'godiste' field as an int and noticed it wasn't working so I changed it to a char and noticed that for some reason my input function 'upis' was attaching the value of the second member of igraci's 'Ime' to the first member's 'godiste'. Can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

I put a printf in main that just prints the 'godiste' of igraci member 0 to make sure it wasn't an issue with my writing function 'ispis' and it is in fact making the value of 'godiste' the 'godiste' of member 0 + the 'ime' of member 1.

'ime' is the player name
'prezime' is the players last name
'pozicija' is the players position
'godiste' is the players birth year

and 'igraci' is a list of players.

The program first asks for the number of players you'd like to input then asks you for their details and prints out what you put in.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct futbaler
    {
        char ime[15];
        char prezime[20];
        char pozicija[15];
        char godiste[4];
    };

void upis(struct futbaler* pok, int n)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Ime igraca #%d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%s",(pok+i)->ime);
        printf("Prezime igraca #%d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%s",(pok+i)->prezime);
        printf("Pozicija igraca #%d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%s",(pok+i)->pozicija);
        printf("Godiste igraca #%d: ",i+1);
        scanf("%s",(pok+i)->godiste);
    }
}

void ispis(struct futbaler* pok, int n)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nIme igraca #%d je: %s\n",i+1,(*(pok+i)).ime);
        printf("\nPrezime igraca #%d je: %s\n",i+1,(*(pok+i)).prezime);
        printf("\nPozicija igraca #%d je: %s\n",i+1,(*(pok+i)).pozicija);
        printf("\nGodiste igraca #%d je: %s\n",i+1,(*(pok+i)).godiste);
    }
}

main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Koliko bi igraca uneli? ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    struct futbaler* pok;
    struct futbaler igraci[n];
    pok = igraci;
    upis(pok,n);
    ispis(pok,n);

    printf("%s",igraci[0].godiste);
}
```

I just want to figgure out why and how it's attaching these values that have nothing to do with eachother together.

Comment: Make sure all your `char` arrays have enough room for the null terminator.

Comment: If `godiste` is a year, then it needs to be `char godiste[5]`. It needs 4 characters for the year, and 1 character for the null.

Comment: BTW, `(pok+i)->ime` and `(*(pok+i)).ime` are more simply written as `pok[i].ime`.

Comment: Your program, **with no changes** (other than adding the return type of `main`) appears to [work as expected in ideone](https://ideone.com/0c4eTg)

Comment: Suggest this: `void upis(ptrdiff_t n, struct futbaler pok[static n])` so that you don't get crazy with pointers.

Comment: Are you providing inputs that are longer than the number of characters allocated for each field? Keep in mind the terminating null characters. For example, `ime[15]` can only hold 14 characters of actual information, since the last character is a terminating null. If you put 15 characters into `ime` and then `printf` it, you'll see `ime` concatenated with `prezime` as you've overwritten the separating null, as they are next to each other in your struct and in memory.

Comment: You don't need `pok`.  `igraci` can be passed to the functions as it decays to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: You should always use `BUFSIZ` as your standard buffer size, unless you have special needs such as a very big buffer, or little memory in an embedded system. That way you will not have to think about how much size you assign to a string. It is defined in `<stdio.h>` and is (around) 4096 if I remember well, so more than enough usually. If you need to fix a different size for the arrays, use a `#define` with an adequate name; that will make you think twice about the size you choose.

Comment: main should be `int main(void)`.  Compile with high warnings always, and only remove them when you know why.  In GCC that will be: `gcc -std=c17 -Wpedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror`

Answer (score 2):

Edited for corrections pointed out by David C. Rankin.

---

The compiler needs to know the length of your array at compile time in order to know how much memory to allocate on the stack. Otherwise, if you do it the way you're doing it right now, by asking the user how big to make the array and then stack-allocating it, you're using a feature known as Variable-Length Arrays (VLAs). This is not a good idea for security reasons.

Having said that, your problem seems to stem from the fact that your year field is a four-character array. Character arrays are strings in C, and by convention they must be nul-terminated to indicate where they stop. Since you're writing a four character value (the year) in a space that can only hold four characters, the result is that the program isn't actually assigning the first element to the last of the previous; what's happening is that when it reads the last field of a struct, it doesn't find a nul terminator and reads right through it. Consequently, an array is a contiguous block of memory, and therefore it sees those two fields as one.

Lastly, I highly recommend you use the more traditional way of dereferencing arrays. `arr[i]` is just syntactic sugar for `*(arr + i)`, but it's a lot easier to read. Not saying it's the root of the problem, but anything that makes your life easier is probably a good idea.

---

This is my implementation of your problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

#ifndef TRUE
enum { FALSE= 0, TRUE = !FALSE };
#endif

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 80

/* munch: remove newline from input buffer */
void munch(char* s) {
    size_t len = strlen(s);

    for (size_t i = len - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        if (s[i] == '\n') {
            s[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
}

void strcpy_(char* s, const char* t) {
    while ((*s++ = *t++) != '\0')
        ;
}

char* strdup_(const char* s) {
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    char* str = malloc((len + 1) * sizeof (char));

    if (str == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[Error] Memory allocation failure\n");

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return memcpy(str, s, len + 1);
}

enum position_t {
    POSITION_UNDEFINED,
    POSITION_STRIKER,
    POSITION_MIDFIELDER,
    POSITION_DEFENDER,
    POSITION_GOALKEEPER
};

const char* position_striker_strings[] = {
    "Striker",
    "striker",
    "False 9",
    "false 9"
};

const char* position_midfielder_strings[] = {
    "Midfielder",
    "midfielder",
    "Centerback",
    "centerback"
};

const char* position_defender_strings[] = {
    "Defender",
    "defender",
    "Fullback",
    "fullback"
};

const char* position_goalkeeper_strings[] = {
    "Goalkeeper",
    "goalkeeper",
    "Goalie",
    "goalie"
};

int position_read(const char* s) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof (position_striker_strings) / sizeof(const char*)); ++i) {
        if (strcmp(s, position_striker_strings[i]) == 0)
            return POSITION_STRIKER;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof (position_midfielder_strings) / sizeof(const char*)); ++i) {
        if (strcmp(s, position_midfielder_strings[i]) == 0)
            return POSITION_MIDFIELDER;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof (position_defender_strings) / sizeof(const char*)); ++i) {
        if (strcmp(s, position_defender_strings[i]) == 0)
            return POSITION_DEFENDER;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < (sizeof (position_goalkeeper_strings) / sizeof(const char*)); ++i) {
        if (strcmp(s, position_goalkeeper_strings[i]) == 0)
            return POSITION_GOALKEEPER;
    }

    return POSITION_UNDEFINED;
}

char* position_str(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case POSITION_STRIKER: {
            return "Striker";
        } break;

        case POSITION_MIDFIELDER: {
            return "Midfielder";
        } break;

        case POSITION_DEFENDER: {
            return "Defender";
        } break;

        case POSITION_GOALKEEPER: {
            return "Goalkeeper";
        } break;

        default: {
            return "Unknown Position Code";
        }
    }
}

struct player_t {
    char* first_name;
    char* last_name;
    int position;
    int year;
};

struct player_t* player_allocate() {
    struct player_t* player = calloc(1, sizeof(struct player_t));

    if (player == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "[Error] Memory allocation failure\n");

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return player;
}

struct player_t* player_new(const char* first_name, const char* last_name, int position, int year) {
    struct player_t* p = player_allocate();

    p->first_name = strdup_(first_name);
    p->last_name = strdup_(last_name);
    p->position = position;
    p->year = year;

    return p;
}

void player_print(struct player_t* player) {
    if (player == NULL)
        return;

    printf("\t%s, %s\n", player->last_name, player->first_name);
    printf("\t\tPosition: %s\n", position_str(player->position));
    printf("\t\tYear: %d\n", player->year);
}

void player_list_print(struct player_t** player_list, size_t n) {
    if (player_list == NULL)
        return;

    printf("\n\nPlayer List: \n\n");

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (player_list[i] == NULL)
            continue;

        player_print(player_list[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n");
}

void clear_buffer(char* buffer, size_t n) {
    memset(buffer, 0, n * sizeof(char));
}

int main(void)
{
    char input_buffer[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
    clear_buffer(input_buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH);

    printf("How many players would you like to enter? ");
    fgets(input_buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, stdin);

    errno = 0;
    char* endptr = NULL;
    long n = strtol(input_buffer, &endptr, 10);

    if ((errno == ERANGE && (n == LONG_MAX || n == LONG_MIN)) || (errno != 0 && n == 0)) {
        perror("strtol");

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (endptr == input_buffer) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No digits were found\n");

        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("Enter %ld player(s).\n", n);

    struct player_t** player_list = calloc(n, sizeof (struct player_t *));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < (size_t) n; ++i) {
        player_list[i] = player_allocate();

        printf("\nFirst Name: ");
        clear_buffer(input_buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
        fgets(input_buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, stdin);
        munch(input_buffer);
        player_list[i]->first_name = strdup_(input_buffer);

        printf("Last Name: ");
        clear_buffer(input_buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
        fgets(input_buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, stdin);
        munch(input_buffer);
        player_list[i]->last_name = strdup_(input_buffer);

        printf("Position: ");
        clear_buffer(input_buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
        fgets(input_buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, stdin);
        munch(input_buffer);
        player_list[i]->position = position_read(strdup_(input_buffer));

        printf("Year: ");
        clear_buffer(input_buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH);
        fgets(input_buffer, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, stdin);
        munch(input_buffer);
        player_list[i]->year = atoi(input_buffer);
    }

    player_list_print(player_list, n);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Program Execution:

```
How many players would you like to enter? 2
Enter 2 player(s).

First Name: Christiano 
Last Name: Ronaldo
Position: Striker
Year: 1985

First Name: Lionel
Last Name: Messi
Position: striker
Year: 1986


Player List: 

    Ronaldo, Christiano
        Position: Striker
        Year: 1985
    Messi, Lionel
        Position: Striker
        Year: 1986
```

You'll notice I wrote my own `strdup_` and `strcpy_` functions. I thought it would be interesting to see how they're implemented, and I also added some functionality to much newline and tab characters. This is because I prefer not to use `scanf`, and so I also included both `atoi` and `strtol` uses in this example.

You'll also notice that `strtol` has a lot of error-checking involved while `atoi` does not; this is precisely why [using atoi is not recommended](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/atoi.html).

Regarding the implementation, since the number of players in the list is indeterminate at compile time I used a double pointer called `player_list` to dynamically allocate each player. To do this, you have to first allocate the `player_list` pointer itself, then iterate through each pointer, individually allocating each player structure in turn.

I also used an integer value for the position and an enumeration for the valid position values. When reading user input I then checked the valid position strings for a match, only adding a specific position if there was indeed a match. This is for data-validation purposes, so that users can't simply add new positions; that would be a database admin's job. Instead the player position is simply set to `POSITION_UNDEFINED` if a match is not found.

The number of valid position strings is calculated based on the number of positions in the array, so you're free to add more valid strings in each position array without worrying about changing the position string matching code.

---

If you simply wanted a basic implementation, you could actually just modify your code slightly to handle the year/terminator problem, and maybe change the name fields to pointers to handle names of any size. As it stands you're vulnerable to a stack overflow. I didn't look too carefully at your input mechanism, but I'm pretty sure there should be superfluous newlines in your input because of the newline character in the input buffer after a call to `scanf`. Might be something to look out for.

Hope this helps, man. I translated the names in your code and if google translate is correct, it was Croatian. If that's true, congrats on getting to the Final last year. Good luck

Comment: `while (*s++ = *t++)`, suggest parentheses around assignment, `error: ‘FALSE’ undeclared`, suggest `#ifndef TRUE enum {FALSE = 0, TRUE = !FALSE} #endif` (`stdbool.h` defines `true` and `false` but not `TRUE` and `FALSE`), `void strncpy_` should be `char *strncpy_`. In `void clear_buffer()`, `n` is unused, it appears you intended `memset(buffer, 0, n);`. Last in `strtol` validation `errno != NULL` is a `comparison between integer and pointer`. Probably mostly copy/paste errors. Good effort.

Comment: Can't believe I missed all that; thank you for the corrections though, I appreciate it. Hopefully I didn't miss anything

Comment: No problem, happens to us all. I just ran it through a compiler and let it help me find the issues `:)`

Comment: Another tweak to your `strdup_` function. Don't scan for end-of-string twice and don't call `realloc` in `strncpy_`, simply use `memcpy` in `strdup_`. You calculate `strlen(s)` with your `calloc` call. Move `size_t len = strlen (s);` above on its own, then `char *str = malloc (len + 1);` (no need for `calloc` you have the *nul-character* in `s`). Now just `return memcpy (str, s, len + 1);`.

Comment: Okay, I made the changes again. I removed the `strncpy_` function, which turned out to be superfluous after your changes, and I added the `munch` function, which eats the newline character in the input buffer after `fgets`. I really like your points on the `strdup_` refactor, I definitely didn't write that as cleanly as I could/should have.

Comment: That is one of the great things about this site. The little tips you get really help deepen and refine your understanding of C. All the tips I've passed along were those that have been passed along to me over the past few years. Keep up the good work.

Comment: Thank you again for the code review, I really appreciate the insight